# Download file Safari

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-mvc, safari

I am trying to trigger file download, and I am having issues to do this on Safari (FireFox & Chrome works as expected).
Here is my Java code:

```
  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "text/csv")
  @ResponseBody
  public String getReports(
      final HttpServletResponse response,
      final @RequestParam String data) throws ParseException {
    response.setHeader("Content-type", "text/csv; charset=utf-8");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename='view.csv'");
    String csv = exportCurrentService.extractMatrix(data);
    response.setContentLength(csv.length());

    return csv;
  }
```

And here is my client code:

```
  downloadURI(url, name) {
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = url;
    a.download = name;
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    document.body.removeChild(a);
  }
```

In Safari the response is printed out on the screen (loaded on the same page).

**Note**: that I have tried other methods suggested on SO but each has it's own problems.

**Update:** In the response header I see that the Content-Disposition is set to inline instead of attachment. Why this is happening?

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Can you use the web inspector in Safari to get the request and response headers, and add them to your question?

Comment: Does changing `Content-Type: text/csv` to `Content-Type: application/octet-stream` do anything for you?

Comment: It downloads but without the file extensions and the file name  (in all browsers)

Comment: Do you have MS Office installed? What OS are you using?

Comment: Yes. Mac OS....

Comment: Check your application settings in Safari. Perhaps it is set to open instead of download.

Comment: It is possible to download from other websites, don't think this is the issue

Comment: You mean you have no problem downloading csv files from other sites? Ugh, what a wrong time not to have a Mac on hand. :(

Comment: Try the solution defined [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31408065/cant-download-file-browser-opens-it-instead).

Comment: @Chad, I don't have a file, I am generating the csv from string (trying to generate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My service is placed behind a routing module (which is the proxy for all the micro services). The issue was in this module (the proxy) it was overwriting the headers and cookies of the micro app service.

Setting the code as described in the question did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

This won't compile, it just represents what you should do.

```java
response.setContentType("application/force-download");
response.setContentLength((int)f.length());
        //response.setContentLength(-1);
response.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\"" + "xxx\"");//fileName);
...
...
File f= new File(fileName);

InputStream in = new FileInputStream(f);
BufferedInputStream bin = new BufferedInputStream(in);
DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(bin);

while(din.available() > 0){
    out.print(din.readLine());
    out.print("\n");
    //this is from another answer I saw awhile ago while trying to do the same thing
}
```

This is from another post that I saw when trying to do the same thing. The original author was Vineet Reynolds. 
I am new to SO so please inform me if this is bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

Try without `@ResponseBody` and with `produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE`

Comment: But I want it as a csv, not json

Comment: You could try with your type (text/csv).
With @ResponseBody annotation you are setting the Content-type header to text/plain.
Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30549204/7604006

Comment: I have tried it but it seems that  Content-Disposition is set to inline, (I see it the dev-tools in the response header).